# Could not run Rake Task in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a rake task which is called by a third party service. In my application I need to set Customer before starting the application. I could not access the model variable from the rake task. But this happens only in Production not in Development. When I run

```
RAILS_ENV = 'production' rake auth:tester
```

I get the followng error.

```
rake aborted!
  Unable to autoload constant CUSTOMER, expected         /home/suganya/academics/tsg-mcds-server/app/models/customer.rb to define it
/home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/home/suganya/academics/tsg-mcds-server/config/initializers/customer_config.rb:11:in `xml'
/home/suganya/academics/tsg-mcds-server/config/initializers/customer_config.rb:38:in `set_customer_settings'
/home/suganya/academics/tsg-mcds-server/config/initializers/customer_config.rb:710:in `<top (required)>'
/home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
```

I have referred all the related questions. When I enable in poduction.rb

```
config.threadsafe!
config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task
```

I get the following error.

```
undefined method `threadsafe!' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000004aebdf8>
```

Also I tried

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

this is my rake task:

```
namespace :authentication do

desc "Automatically runs authentication tester"

task :tester => :environment do
Rake.application.rake_require "#{Rails.root}/config/initialize_customer_in_development.rb"

begin
  AuthenticationTester.perform
rescue
  SystemEvent.error(50049, "Authentication Tester Finished Unsuccessfully.")
end
end
```

end

Nothing helped. please help to solve this problem.

Comment: How does your rake task look like? How does `app/models/customer.rb` look like?

Comment: The error message tells you that Rails was `unable to autoload constant CUSTOMER`. Where do you call `CUSTOMER`, where did you define `CUSTOMER`?

Comment: It is defined in config/initialize_customer_in_development.rb and config/initializers/customer_config.rb